# tabbed content not working in Chrome and Firefox but works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i have this index.js which contains most of my functions like :

```
      // a and b is placed at index.jsp 
$("#a").click(function (){  //this works on index.jsp and display.jsp(where the servlets forwards it).
      $("#b").load('servletA.html?action=display');
 });
```

I also have another tabbedcontent.js import on my index.jsp and display.jsp, the problem is when i run my display.jsp solely, the tabbed content works. but unfortunately if i click `#a` at my index.jsp the tabbed content is not working. I wonder why it doesn't in Chrome and Firefox. but it does work in IE(all versions).

EDITED :

here is a code snipper from display.jsp

```
 // imports
  <script src="js/tabcontent.js"></script>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#view1">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="#view2">OTHERS</a></li>
   </ul>
    <div class="tabcontent">
        <div id="view1">
              // SOME CONTENT HERE
        </div>
        <div id="view2">
              // SOME CONTENT HERE
        </div>
```

Comment: could you please share a code on fiddle?

Comment: it will contain 3 files. 2 jsps and a servlet.

Comment: No need to jsps, only HTML/JS

Comment: i've DLed my tabbed content on this [site](http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content)   [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ejay/45D6W/)

Comment: Sorry, but i still need to HTML/JS to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it is this way

```
$("#b").load('servletA.html', {action: 'display'});
```

It might help you. Read more about [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Basically this is the syntax

```
$('#mydiv').load('newPage.html', {field1: 'value1', ...});
```

---

validate the path of `servletA.html` again. try with `/servletA.html`.

Comment: my tabbed content still won't work on the loaded display.jsp on div `#b` but other personally written javascript and jquery works.

Comment: Can you share some piece of code to investigate it more? Share relevant code of `display.jsp`.